# Set panel.screen in kde plasma javascript console

Tags: javascript, kde-plasma

I'm trying to programically set panel location. I'm using:

```
qdbus org.kde.plasmashell /PlasmaShell org.kde.PlasmaShell.showInteractiveConsole
```

I have determined that when I manually drag panel to other screen I get `0` and `1` from `panel.screen`. Unfortunately moving the panel does not work with this script:

```
var panel = panelById(1);
print("screenCount: " + screenCount);
print("panel.screen: " + panel.screen);
panel.screen = 0;
print("panel.screen: " + panel.screen);
```

The panel stays in it's place and I get in output:

```
screenCount: 6
panel.screen: 1
panel.screen: 1
```

When I try with things like

```
panel.location = "top";
panel.location = "bottom";
```

it works as expected.

Resources:

- [PlasmaDesktopScripting](https://userbase.kde.org/KDE_System_Administration/PlasmaDesktopScripting#Panels)

Comment: Asked also here https://superuser.com/questions/1081120/how-do-i-move-a-kde-plasma-panel-from-commandline-scripts that, I think is a better place, maybe join the conversation. We have to find a solution ;-)